# bootstrap c при помощи npm и webpack

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap, npm, webpack

Я создал небольшое приложение и хочу подключить туда `bootstrap`. Ввожу команду:

```
npm install bootstrap --save-dev
```

В итоге вижу в папке `node_modules/bootstrap` лежит все, что нужно: `css`, `fonts` и `js`. Как мне все это подключить из проекта ? Например, с `angular` все просто:

```
var angular = require('angular');
var ngModule = angular.module('superApp', []);
```

Но что мне делать с подключением стилей ?

Comment: там нужно штуки четыре лоадера, css-loader, style-loader и два для картинок, какие точно не понмю

Comment: а, возможно для шрифтов еще отдельно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну подключать js так же как подключать angular. Только бутстрап работает исключительно через jquery, поэтому не уверен, что вам нужен такой уг.
Судя по всему, у вас angular проект, тогда используйте [angular bootstrap](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/).

Для подключение стилей вам нужно минимум 2 лоадера css-loader и style-loader.
[Ссылки на гайд из доков](http://webpack.github.io/docs/stylesheets.html).
Я себя умным не считаю, поэтому иногда смотрю скринкасты по сложным инструментам. Вот [скринкаст от Кантора](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLDyvV36pndZHfBThhg4Z0822EEG9VGenn), который подробно рассказывает как работать с вебпаком, там есть и ролик про то как подключить стили и работать с ними.